# How to convert aws commands to cdk commands in buildspec.yml?

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-codebuild

In the buildspec.yml, aws codes is -

```
post_build:
commands:
  - aws s3 cp --recursive --acl public-read dist/ s3://com-abc-${xyz}-random
```

So, how can i replace `aws s3 cp --recursive --acl public-read dist/ s3://com-abc-${xyz}-random` command with cdk command ?

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no cdk equivalent to this.

Comment: @luk2302 other than cdk , is there any way to replace that with linux commands?

Comment: Why? Of course you can replicate this without using the aws cli but that requires A LOT of code, all the code and logic that the aws cli is there to provide.

Comment: There’s no such thing as CDK command. CDK just renders to CloudFormation template and deploys it.

Comment: But there’s a construct DeploymentBucket that can probably do what you are looking for. It uploads an asset to the asset bucket on deploy and then copies the contents to the bucket of your choice.

Comment: @moltar i saw about `s3deploy.BucketDeployment`  but how to use that for copying  recursively using cdk because docs said about creating noting about copying like the `cp` command? also for that  i need to create a stack?

Comment: BucketDeployment copies everything recursively.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

That part of your buildspec happens *during the build*. CDK commands - and SDK programming inside your CDK stacks - *only happen during cdk synth or cdk deploy* - those are the only two commands that have active deployment options.

Even tho you could write some SDK programming to accomplish this same thing, *it would happen before your resources are deployed, as all sdk commands inside a CDK stack run during synth*

I assume what you are trying to do here is make use of just cdk deploy to replace whatever else this code build is doing. In which case, you can't. What you can do however, is wrap your cdk deploy + this command + any others in your own bash script to run when you want to run it.

Or just move your cdk deploy command as part of your codebuild. (if you do not have a complex build that requires a lot of moving parts, ie say a headless microservice made up of a few lambdas and storage options, a code build running cdk deploy is a perfectly fine way to deploy in the middle of a pipeline)